# Make sessions last until browser closes PHP

Tags: php, linux, hosting

I'm working on cpanel Linux Godaddy hosting, I don't have access to php.ini

I've created **.user.ini**

Worked fine for changing settings, I have the values and as I upload a change, configuration changes inmediately.

My problem is that sessions won't last, although session.cookie_lifetime=0 and session.gc_maxlifetime=0, they close without closing the browser.

Does other directives have something to do? What's the difference between local and master value, is master value above local? as session.gc_maxlifetime=1440 and set to 0 by me on the .user.ini

[phpinfo.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhUpX.png)

Answer (score 1):

`session.cookie_lifetime` tells the client browser how long to keep the cookie around, and a setting of `0` discards the cookie when the browser/tab is closed.

`session.gc_maxlifetime` tells PHP the maximum possible age of session files when running a cleanup, and a setting of `0` means that any time session GC [probabilistic, [see docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime)] runs all sessions that haven't been touched in longer than 0 seconds will be cleaned up, which is all of them.

You should understand that PHP sessions denote no persistence between the client and the server. A PHP session is just a blob of data identified by a token which is served to the client browser as a cookie, which is then passed back on subsequent requests.

**TLDR:** Your `session.cookie_lifetime` setting is fine, but setting `session.gc_maxlifetime` to zero is causing your issue. Return it to its default value, which is usually a day or two, or determine a value that balances user convenience with whatever reason you want to clean up old session files.

Comment: Is there an unlimited value I can set? I thought 0 was that. in my case I wouldn't like to restore that token. Insted I prefer the user to logout if he deserves and keep the session open indefinitely, or until browser closes

Comment: The longer you set that timeout the more session files you will accumulate until it starts to cause FS problems. Besides, the limit affects _untouched_ session files. Every time the user make a request that calls `session_start()` the timer is reset. Set a reasonable timeout value, and don't make yourself responsible for users that forget about their open tabs and/or have unreasonable expectations.

Comment: Suppose 60*60*24*7=604800 a week. Do you consider too much? I guess there won't be that many user so to expect problems. This is for a gym booking system, and for this users I think is better not to be logging in each time they want to make a reservation, I think it makes the product better

Comment: YMMV. There is no particular "right answer" as it depends on your app, traffic frequency/patterns, your/your users' expectations, and what can be reasonably accommodated by your infrastructure. Keep an eye on the session dir, and not just the size but also the file count. inode exhaustion is a thing.

Comment: Still not working, session keeps closing. session.gc_maxlifetime=86400, is the only directive inside the .user.ini file at the moment.

Comment: I found this, I have a dilemma, should I insist on changing the value?
https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.security.ini.php

session.gc_maxlifetime is a setting for deleting obsolete session ID. Reliance on this setting is not recommended. Developers should manage the lifetime of sessions with a timestamp by themselves.